# Privacy concern on ShareLatex

Tags: sharelatex

When I upload my work on ShareLatex, what are the privacy obligation of this online Tex editor? I mean what if my work get stolen or lost from this online editor?

Comment: Read this: https://www.sharelatex.com/tos and this: https://www.sharelatex.com/privacy_policy. It says that the data are yours and will not be shared if you don't chose to share them (So that will be consider as forbidden by international laws), that it saves on servers (and thus you can never be sure that nobody sees your work even if it is forbidden) and that they don't promise to have available their services forever. (Thus save your work because if lost it is nobody's fault).